# How to add Textviews next to each other and move them to the next line if they dont fit

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 5 textviews, each textview has its own background and they are one next to the other,
their sizes change depending on the amount of text that I put in them. I want to know if 
at any point they stop fitting because they reach the border of the parent. But not only that if they dont fit I want to be able to add something like "click here to see more". So how do I detect how much space have they taken so far as I go adding the text to them? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TextUtils.ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#ellipsize%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20float,%20android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29). 
Maintain the actual text in a member. Call ellipsize with the text as parameter and set the returned text to the textview. 
You can set a callback `TextUtils.EllipsizeCallback` which will be called when the text gets ellipsized.

```
TextUtils.EllipsizeCallback ellipsizeCallback = new TextUtils.EllipsizeCallback(){
     void ellipsized(int start, int end) {
         // enable the `click here to see more` button.
     }
}

...
CharSequence elipsizedText = ellipsize (mtext, mtxtpaint, 
                                        avail, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END , 
                                        preserveLength, ellipsizeCallback);
tv.setText(mtext);
```